# Get all categories of a product

Tags: php, arrays, woocommerce

I want to show all categories of a product to the class of each product.
If a product belongs to many categories, it only displays the last category in many categories of a product. I want it to display the full categories.
I use the code below:

```
<?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    global $product, $post;
    $classes = '';

    $terms_id     = array();
    $item_cats    = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
    if ( $item_cats ) :
        foreach ( $item_cats as $item_cat ) {
            $classes = urldecode( $item_cat->slug ) . ' ';
        }
    endif;
    ?>

    <li class="<?php echo esc_attr($classes) ?>">
        <div class="content_product">
        </div>
    </li>
<?php endwhile;
```

Comment: You missed `concat` symbol, `$classes .= `

Comment: This looks much better for me now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shows the last category because in your foreach loop you reassign eachtime in the same variable instead of concatenate it (or pushing it in an array).

```
foreach ( $item_cats as $item_cat ) {
        $classes = urldecode( $item_cat->slug ) . ' ';
    }
```

You should go for:

```
$classes = [];
foreach ( $item_cats as $item_cat ) {
        $classes[] = urldecode( $item_cat->slug ) . ' ';
    }
```

And

```
<li class="<?php echo esc_attr(implode(' ', $classes)) ?>">
```

**EDIT:**
Or simply without any array (because of the simple nature of what need to be displayed):

```
foreach ( $item_cats as $item_cat ) {
        $classes .= urldecode( $item_cat->slug ) . ' ';
    }
```

Comment: This looks much better for me now.