# Get a list of all categories a product belongs to in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In WooCommerce attributes i'm trying to show a list of product-categories the product belongs to.

My code only shows 1 product-category. The product is in multiple product-categories.

I already checked this page [Get all categories of a product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52757114/get-all-categories-of-a-product) but this solutions didn't worked for me.

What am i missing in my code?

This goes in product-attributes.php:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
        foreach ($terms  as $term  ) {
            $product_cat_name = $term->name ;
            break;
        } ?>
        <tr class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item woocommerce-product-attributes-item--<?php echo esc_attr( $product_attribute_key ); ?>">
        <th class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__label">Categorie</th>
         <td class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value" ><?php echo esc_attr( $product_cat_name ); ?></td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: Are you aware that `break;` is used in your foreach loop?

Comment: Yes...I just wanted to answer my own question!
The correct output is shown now.

Thanks